Z253 and N1 marking on chips - identification
I have two chips that I don't really know what they could be. The chips with the Z253 marking are connected to a connector, micro and some other things; whereas the N1 marked chips are connected to an op amp. The N1 chip I think could be a transistor, just because of the way it looks. The Z253 I think could be a voltage regulator, just because it is connected to ground for both the op amp and the ADC and its in between micro and ADC. I am not too sure though, as I don't have a lot of experience with reverse engineering.



Please add dimensions.

@nanash1 I don't have calipers at the moment, but measuring with the ruler, N1 is 4x2 mm and Z253 is 2x1 mm

Z253 is an Onsemi NC7SZ125P5X UHS buffer.


(Source: taobao)

N1 is a Diodes Inc FCX491 NPN BJT.


(Source: lcsc.com)
